# How to calculate area using QgsDistanceArea?

Tags: qgis, python-2.7

I am trying the following code as given in the QGIS documentation:

```
d = QgsDistanceArea()
d.setProjectionsEnabled(True)

print "distance in meters: ", d.measureLine(QgsPoint(10,10),QgsPoint(11,11))
```

But getting the following error:

> " AttributeError: 'QgsDistanceArea' object has no attribute 'setProjectionsEnabled' "

What is wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think a similar problem was asked [here](http://osgeo-org.1560.x6.nabble.com/QgsDistanceArea-td5140588.html) where it is mentioned that the cookbook should be updated.  From the link given, you should replace `setProjectionsEnabled` with `setEllipsoidalMode`.